# Uninstaller that can work with failed installs

Tags: windows-7, windows, software-rec, 64-bit

I'd like an application that can uninstall applications that does not show up in the normal add/remove applications.

I have an application that failed to install properly. It installs half way and then crashes leaving shortcuts, folders with exe and config files in and some stuff in the registry.

Ideally I would like to be able to point the uninstaller to the install dir and tell it to remove everything that references files in that dir.

Comment: Write one! It's situations like this that make knowing a scripting language like Python invaluable.

Comment: @Phoshi - But, but... I'm lazy! It even says so on my profile page. If nothing emerges here I *might* fix something with `perl` and `Win32::TieRegistry`

Comment: Hey, I'm lazy too - only difference is I absolutely love python, and generally take any excuse I can get to write in it :P

Answer (score 1):

Try [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/), it was able to clean up a couple of my failed installs.

Comment: Revo can't find it. Probably because it never got so far as to create an entry in add/remove programs

Comment: Also, Revo is not 64-bit compatible (last I heard...)

Comment: @outside - Revo have a 64-bit version nowadays

Answer (score 0):

Use RollbackRX befor any install (take snapshot of the system) and if it fails you can reboot to the snapshot you just took in only a few minutes.

Comment: Good advice but not the answer I was looking for. Rolling back the system all the time is not an attractive option when you are debugging a faulty installer.